# extracting abstract and external wiki links from a dbpedia page using sparql

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have a query that finds the uri of websites which has information about sachin tendulkar. there are 2 columns in my result first is for uri and second is for little information. I want to add third column for abstract of every dbpedia web page and 4th column for external wiki links. 
my query for finding uri is...

```
 select ?s1 as ?c1, ( bif:search_excerpt ( bif:vector ( 'SACHIN', 'TENDULKAR' ) , ?o1 ) ) as ?c2     where 
{ 
 { 
  { 
    select ?s1, ( ?sc * 3e-1 ) as ?sc, ?o1, ( sql:rnk_scale ( <LONG::IRI_RANK> ( ?s1 ) ) ) as ?rank, ?g where 
    { 
      quad map virtrdf:DefaultQuadMap 
      { 
        graph ?g 
        { 
          ?s1 ?s1textp ?o1 .
          ?o1 bif:contains ' ( SACHIN AND TENDULKAR ) ' option ( score ?sc ) .

        }
       }
     }
   order by desc ( ?sc * 3e-1 + sql:rnk_scale ( <LONG::IRI_RANK> ( ?s1 ) ) ) limit 20 offset 0 
  }
 }
}
```

I have also a separate query for extracting abstract from any dbpedia page. and i want to merge both the queries into one. the query for extracting abstract is...

```
select ?abs where { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Haldia_Institute_of_Technology> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?abs                                                                                                                            FILTER (langMatches(lang(?abs),"en")) }
```

Comment: What do you need help with?

Comment: i have written in question that i want to merge these two queries for getting 4 columns from sparql query when i run that merged query in virtuoso.. I am new at dealing with sparql query so i don't know how to get results by merging queries..

Comment: "I want ..." is not really a question. :) So your question is: "How do I get results for four variables with SPARQL?" That is a an easy question to answer: `SELECT ?v1 ?v2 ?v3 ?v4 WHERE { ... }` is the basic pattern for such a query. http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/sparql.html has tutorials.